# Custom value on model when AngularJS $asyncValidator's promise rejects

Tags: angularjs, validation

I'm running a custom async validator on an input field through a directive:

```
angular.module("app", [])
.directive("accountDescriptionValidator", function ($q, $timeout) {
    function startValidation() {
      var startValidationDeferred = $q.defer();
      $timeout(function() { startValidationDeferred.resolve() }, 100);
      return startValidationDeferred.promise;
    }
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        require: "ngModel",
        scope: {
            parentModel: "="
        },
        link: function (scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$asyncValidators["accountDescriptionValidator"] = function (modelValue, viewValue) {
                var accountDescriptionValidatorDefer = $q.defer();
                startValidation().then(function(accounts) {
                    if (viewValue == "aaa") {
                      accountDescriptionValidatorDefer.reject();
                    }
                    else {
                      accountDescriptionValidatorDefer.resolve();
                    }
                });
                return accountDescriptionValidatorDefer.promise;
            };
        }
    };
})
```

The validator does its job greatly; however when the validation (rightfully) fails, the model bound to the input field is deleted from its parent object altogether. Instead, what I'd like is to keep the latest valid value in it. Is this possible?

EDIT: plnkr added [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/EE7L04kno3LvkceX4vCK?p=preview)

EDIT2: now the question code matches the plnkr one

Comment: if you could add a demo example using something like jsfiddle would help to understand the problem better and early resolution.

Comment: You'll need to require 'ngModel' in your directive and access the ngModelController to modify the $modelValue.

Comment: @ShaunScovil as you can see, ngModel is already required. However, I'm about to provide a plunkr with an example; would you care to elaborate your answer?

Answer (score 3):

I see two solutions to your problem.

- Use another variable and it keep the last correct value.
- Use the [allowInvalid](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngModelOptions) option.

Live example on [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/rmIbfCrqn2BI2kR0tPSs?p=preview).

```js
// Code goes here

angular.module("app", [])
  .directive("accountDescriptionValidator", function($q, $timeout) {
    function startValidation() {
      var startValidationDeferred = $q.defer();
      $timeout(function() {
        startValidationDeferred.resolve()
      }, 100);
      return startValidationDeferred.promise;
    }
    return {
      restrict: "A",
      require: "ngModel",
      scope: {
        parentModel: "=",
        lastValidValue: "="
      },
      link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl) {
        ctrl.$asyncValidators["accountDescriptionValidator"] = function(modelValue, viewValue) {
          var accountDescriptionValidatorDefer = $q.defer();
          startValidation().then(function(accounts) {
            if (viewValue == "aaa") {
              console.log('invalid');
              accountDescriptionValidatorDefer.reject();
            } else {
              scope.lastValidValue = modelValue;
              accountDescriptionValidatorDefer.resolve();
            }
          });
          return accountDescriptionValidatorDefer.promise;
        };
      }
    };
  })
  .controller("ctrl", function($scope) {
    $scope.obj = {};
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.0" data-semver="1.5.0" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.0/angular.js"></script>
</head>

<body ng-app="app">
  <div ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="text" ng-model="obj.description" account-description-validator last-valid-value="obj.lastDescription" />
    <br>Current value:{{ obj.description }}

    <br>Last valid value:{{ obj.lastDescription }}
    <br>By inserting "aaa" (without quotes) in the text field validation fails, and the model gets deleted! Instead, I'd like the model to be kept to the latest valid value. Validation has 100ms delay to simulate an async action.
    <br>
    <input type="text" ng-model="obj.description2" ng-model-options="{allowInvalid:true}" account-description-validator last-valid-value="obj.lastDescription2" />
    <br>Current value with allow invalid:{{ obj.description2 }}
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: So, I played a bit with your suggestions. Both of them don't really do what I want, however I appreciate your effort. As of now I ended up simply with the allowInvalid option, and I'll keep my invalid value in the model anyway. I'll see if I can manage this in some other way.

Comment: Please explain why you did not like the version with `lastValidValue`.

Comment: Because I would need that value saved to the model itself, not on another value in the scope. This is because my form is a "live editing" form, I have no "Apply" button. I need that value immediately in the model, because if an user navigates away from the form the last valid value should be in the model already.

Comment: The value in the model, and the value displayed in the INPUT will be different, if not passed validation? What behavior should be, if you did not pass the validation? What should be displayed in the INPUT?